# Accessing data in second table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am retrieving a list of projects like so

```
$projects = Project::select('id', 'projectnName', 'projectContact', 'deploymentDate')->get();
```

In the select part, I could add `client_id` which will return the id of the client.  However, this is linked to an id in my clients table, and I want to select the clients name.  I have been trying the following
before the select

```
join('clients', 'clients.id', '=', 'projects.client_id')
```

But that seems to fail.  How can I access the `clientName` via the `client_id`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Laravel relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships) are great for easily doing this.

You should create a `Client` model in your `app` directory:

```
namespace App;

class Client extends Eloquent
{
    //
}
```

Then, in your `Project` model, define a `client()` method:

```
class Project extends Eloquent
{
    public function client()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Client::class);
    }
}
```

Then, when you query your `Project` model:

```
public function index()
{
    $projects = Project::with('client')->get();

    foreach ($projects as $project) {

        // Retrieve the client name of the project:

        $client = $project->client->clientName;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add clients.name (table_name.column_name) in your select statement like below:

```
$projects = Project::select('clients.name','clients.id', 'projectnName', 'projectContact', 'deploymentDate') 
->join('clients', 'clients.id', '=', 'projects.client_id')
->get();
```